# Parse.com month issue

Tags: javascript, date

In a google spreadsheet cell i have this date 25/07/2005.
And also i have this as a part of my appscript in google spreadsheet

```
if (cellDataString.substring(2,3) === '/' && cellDataString.substring(5,6) === '/') {
    var year = cellDataString.substring(6,10);
    var month = cellDataString.substring(3,5);
    var day = cellDataString.substring(0,2);    



    var formatedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(year, month, day) , "GMT+0530", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

    var requiredData = {
      "__type": "Date",
      "iso": formatedDate
    }
    Logger.log(requiredData);
    cellData = requiredData;
  }
```

But when i run this script and upload data to parse.com,one month gets incremented to the required month, instead of 25/07/2005(July 27 2005) i am getting August 27 2005(27/08/2005). Instead of using "month - 1" is there any other right way to upload the correct date?.

Comment: *"Instead of using "month - 1" is there any other right way to upload the correct date?"* Nope. I mean, you could use a library like http://momentjs.com/ which does all the parsing and formatting for you. But if you don't want to use another library, then no.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Felix Kling, momentjs.com is news for me, I will definitely check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript dates use months numbered 0 through 11.  Try replacing line 3 of your code with this:

```
var month = cellDataString.substring(3,5) - 1;
```

Comment: Why are you calling `parseInt`?

Comment: @FelixKling - yes, you're correct, not needed here.  Updated, and thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @MattJohnson I am going to use momentjs library